# MySQL delete from Multiple tables using ON not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete from multiple tables with the following query

```
mysql>         DELETE
    ->           info, pagelets, shingles, links
    ->         FROM
    ->           info
    ->         INNER JOIN pagelets
    ->           ON info.page_key=144
    ->           AND info.page_key=pagelets.page_key
    ->         INNER JOIN shingles
    ->           ON pagelets.pagelet_serial=shingles.pagelet_serial
    ->         INNER JOIN links
    ->           ON pagelets.pagelet_serial=links.pagelet_serial
    -> ;
Query OK, 2050 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM info;
+--------+----------+
| netloc | page_key |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        2 |
|      1 |      118 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM pagelets WHERE page_key =144;
+----------+----------------+
| page_key | pagelet_serial |
+----------+----------------+
|      144 |            245 |
|      144 |            246 |
|      144 |            249 |
|      144 |            253 |
```

Unfortunately, this only works on a the table links and info. ( Don' tknow why it doens't work on pagelets and shingles)

The original query was:

```
#        DELETE 
#          info, pagelets, shingles, links
#        FROM
#          info INNER JOIN pagelets INNER JOIN shingles INNER JOIN links
#        WHERE
#          info.page_key=%(page_key)s
#          AND info.page_key=pagelets.page_key
#          AND pagelets.pagelet_serial=shingles.pagelet_serial
#          AND pagelets.pagelet_serial=links.pagelet_serial
#
```

any one can explain this mystery?

Comment: and the original query doesn't work (you will probably guessed it by now)

Comment: The sample data you show has no matching rows between info and pagelets, so it's no wonder the DELETE isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete from info and every other tabled joined to info. The syntax is misleading, I know, but it will work!

```
DELETE 
  info
FROM
  info INNER JOIN pagelets INNER JOIN shingles INNER JOIN links
WHERE
  info.page_key=%(page_key)s
  AND info.page_key=pagelets.page_key
  AND pagelets.pagelet_serial=shingles.pagelet_serial
  AND pagelets.pagelet_serial=links.pagelet_serial
```

By the way, I know that this is an ancient post, but there are many users that find this post when searching for an answer, so there really is no such thing as ancient! -Rance

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table names listed to delete into this :

```
DELETE info.*, pagelets.*, shingles.*, links.*
```

Comment: I tried using this: 
        DELETE
          info.*, pagelets.*, shingles.*, links.*
        FROM 
          info
        INNER JOIN pagelets 
          ON info.page_key=pagelets.page_key
        INNER JOIN shingles           
          ON  pagelets.pagelet_serial=shingles.pagelet_serial         
        INNER JOIN links           
          ON pagelets.pagelet_serial=links.pagelet_serial
        WHERE
          info.page_key=118

but it still didn't work

Comment: try "USING" syntax in sql for multiple table delection

Comment: @yoda: The USING syntax will be ambiguous and because more than two tables contain the `pagelet_serial` column.  This is an error.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner alternative would be to use foreign key restrictions with `ON DELETE CASCADE` in these dependent tables (pagelets, shingles, links) so that the delete statement doesn't need to be so complicated.

Comment: MYISAM dose not support foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

Try this query as an experiment:

```
SELECT * FROM info
INNER JOIN pagelets ON (info.page_key = pagelets.page_key)
LEFT JOIN shingles ON (pagelets.pagelet_serial = shingles.pagelet_serial)
LEFT JOIN links ON (pagelets.pagelet_serial = links.pagelet_serial)
WHERE info.page_key = 144;
```

You'll probably see NULL in either the `shingles` and `links` columns, and no overlap between these.  That is, there's no row in `pagelets` that joins to both `links` and `shingles`.  So if you change to an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM info
INNER JOIN pagelets ON (info.page_key = pagelets.page_key)
INNER JOIN shingles ON (pagelets.pagelet_serial = shingles.pagelet_serial)
INNER JOIN links ON (pagelets.pagelet_serial = links.pagelet_serial)
WHERE info.page_key = 144;
```

You'll get an empty set.

When you do a `DELETE` of course it deletes zero rows because the joins result in an empty set.

As for your question about why does this delete from two tables but not the others, I have to question this.  I think you made a mistake, because I can't see how it could do that.